# Error: Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Applications/iWork '09/Pages.app/.../Contents/Resources

Tags: objective-c, iphone

When I am building my project it is showing the following error. This is the first time Im facing this error:

> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Applications/iWork '09/Pages.app/Contents/Resources/Templates/Modern Business Cards.template/Contents/Resources.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an Xcode "problem", as the error is generated from having a recursive search in your header search path. I've solved this in the past by unchecking the "Recursive" flag on items in the **Header search path** and *instead* link to each directory *directly*. There might be other (better) ways to solve this problem but it appears to be somewhat a bug with Xcode not reporting the error correctly when it is hit with a path it can not fully resolve.

There is also some info here about this error:

[Xcode 3.1 problem checking dependencies | Cocoabuilder](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/266490-xcode-3-1-problem-checking-dependencies.html)

There someone wrote,

> Since GCC doesn't natively support
>   recursive search paths, Xcode
>   simulates them by expanding such a
>   path into a discrete -I or -F or -L
>   flag for each directory under the
>   parent directory, but this can rapidly
>   expand to the point that it results in
>   a command line too long to be issued.
>
> The difference between Xcode 3.0 and
>   3.1 here is that Xcode 3.0 would silently stop expanding the recursive
>   search path if it got too long and
>   simply use whatever it had computed up
>   to that point, which would result in
>   semi-deterministic (and extremely
>   difficult to diagnose) errors for
>   certain types of projects.  So now
>   Xcode emits an error if it was unable
>   to fully expand the recursive search
>   path.
>
> So you may need to remove that
>   recursive search path, or modify it to
>   expand to a smaller set of
>   directories, or convert it to a
>   smaller set of non-recursive search
>   paths.  Or, alternately, reorganize
>   your source to have fewer directories
>   the path can expand to.
>
> Incidentally, having a smaller set of
>   expansions could also lead to
>   somewhat-faster compilation times,
>   since it's fewer directories that the
>   compiler has to search in when
>   compiling each file.  (I don't know
>   the magnitude of impact this would
>   have, though.)

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same error today.

My problem was within Build Settings where I had this setting
**USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = ../../****

Since I had moved the project around in the file system, the parent-parent-dir no longer pointed to the root of the project, but instead it pointed to the folder with all the projects I have ever made.

I solved it by changing it to point the root folder of the project, like this:
**USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = ../****

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3491360/1270459) saved my day. My suggestion is that make sure you don't have "/**" or "$(inherited)/**" in your **Header Search Paths** *and* **Library Search Paths**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build log and grab the full error message.  It should give you more information as to exactly what was happening when the error was thrown.

---

Dependency analysis failure, huh?

Sounds like you have a file reference somewhere in the project to an iWork template or to some similar file that shouldn't be referenced.

Comment: Check dependencies

Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Applications/iWork '09/Pages.app/Contents/Resources/Templates/Modern Business Cards.template/Contents/Resources.

this is what Im getting in build result...

Answer (score 0):

Check dependencies.
Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed

Please check your source tree.
Xcode - Preference - Source Tree.

I was also facing the same problem.The code was compiling on my mac but is giving error when compiling on another mac.
 Found the solution by making changes in source tree.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the correct answer was already shared but I'll share another scenario where you can have the same error.

I had the same problem in my case was related with the Derived Data. After clean the Derived Data folder the problem disappeared.