# Error : Argument list too long:recursive header expansion failed at /Applications/Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional/Adobe Acrobat Professional.app/

Tags: xcode

Can Any one tell why this error occur and how to resolve it

> Check Dependencies
>
> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at
>   /Applications/Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional/Adobe Acrobat
>   Professional.app/Contents/Plug-ins/Comments.acroplugin/Contents/MacOS.

Comment: How is Acrobat related to iPhone programming ??? What did you do???

Comment: My error was mentioning Adobe Illustrator, the app has nothing to do with the error--it is probably picking the first folder in the /Applications folder.

Comment: Me too (to help Googlers find this topic): Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed at /Applications/iWork '09/Keynote.app/Contents/Resources/Themes/Industrial_1024x768.kth/theme-files

Comment: I removed any recursive entries that may be redundant but cleaning did not help. I had to restart xcode before a clean did the trick.

Answer (score 63):

in my case the error was empty variable in "Header Search Paths" field (in project information) with recursion enabled.

This lead to pass value "/**" to a tool.

Comment: Fixed the problem for me as well. @CristinaMartin: if this worked, you should accept this answer.

Comment: And to be clear, the fix is to remove this variable.  (At least for me anyways.)

Comment: Worked for me!  In my case I added the necessary path variable under Preferences/Source Trees and that did it.

Comment: Worked for me too, I had a XCode environment variable in the "Header Search Paths" and if it is not defined XCode crashes when trying to index the code.

Comment: Worked for me too. I got a "/**" in Library Search Paths which gave me the error.

Comment: in my case was the PODS_ROOT variable was empty

Answer (score 5):

I'll share another scenario where you can have the same error.

I had the same problem in my case was related with the Derived Data. After clean the Derived Data folder the problem disappeared.

Comment: That did it for me. I had removed files out of a project, compiles and run and all was fine. After commit, wouldn't build any more. Deleting the Derived Data folder cleaned out the build.

Comment: Maybe one day Xcode will actually "clean" when performing a "clean".

Answer (score 2):

I just removed all entries under framework search paths.
It works fine, in some other cases you may need to enable always search user paths flag to true.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, deleting the build folder worked.

```
rm -rf ios/build
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Project build settings Framework Search Paths I replaced:

`/Users/My.Name/Documents/My-Project/**`

with

`/Users/My.Name/Documents/My-Project/`

Answer (score 0):

A different solution for me.
I am using a static lib in my XCode project. 
In XCode preferences > Source trees I set  up the lib as follows:

Setting Name:
MY_IPHONE_LIB

Display Name:
MY_IPHONE_LIB

Path:
../../MyIphoneLib

Then in the project and target build options User Header Search Paths I add recursive path to $(MY_IPHONE_LIB) this shows as ../../MyIphoneLib** in the build settings

My problem was I had a trailing space after the path in project trees so instead of "../../MyIphoneLib" I had entered "../../MyIphoneLib "

So this all looked fine in the settings but I got the 'argument list too long' error for a completely unrelated file!. Removing the trailing space fixed it.

Comment: Removing the trailing space fixed it.?

Answer (score 0):

the only thing to remove is search path from project information this solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved by revising Framework SearchPaths in .xcodeproj to

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)/../../../ios/Pods.
```

Answer (score 0):

For future folks ... I faced this issue for a different reason.

Just check in your `Project Settings` that `Build System` is set to `New Build System (Default)`

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react native and run into this error, this helped me:

I had to use `react-native unlink xxx` to unlink the library i was trying to add which caused this error to occur (funny enough the error was about a different library not the one i just added)

After unlinking i followed the steps the library explained in its readme on how to add it manually without using the react native link, then it was happy after that.

Saw on reddit that a lot of people been complaining that `react-native link` breaks quite often and causes problems like this